# how to delete folder of spring sts tool form windows 8.1

Tags: windows, spring-mvc, filesystems

[I want to work with new spring sts tool and delete old folder but It generate error file name is too long and rename option also not available. You can see the image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMbWU.jpg)

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMbWU.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Try deleting rather than moving to the recycle bin.

Comment: shift delete, delete both option not work. every time display same error file name is too long.

Comment: Awesome.  Perhaps you can just move the entire directory out of your way and ignore it?  Or move it to a higher level in the hierarchy and then delete it.  Or you might be able to use a linux system to delete it.